# How can we get the data for a player within a 45 days report rolling period

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sql table cool off which has records as shown below

| AccountID | CoolOff_Created_DT | CoolOff_End_DT | Endcycle45days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 10-01-2022 00:48 | 13-01-2022 05:00 | 27-02-2022 05:00 |
| 12345 | 13-01-2022 11:43 | 17-01-2022 05:00 | 03-03-2022 05:00 |
| 12345 | 20-01-2022 03:42 | 23-01-2022 05:00 | 09-03-2022 05:00 |
| 12345 | 23-01-2022 15:32 | 29-01-2022 05:00 | 15-03-2022 05:00 |

---

I need  a sql query to get the records for each accountid within the first cycleend45daysperiod(27-02-2022) from the first cool off end date (13-01-2022)

Output in physical table for the first cycle should be something like shown below and next cycle will start after end of 45 days cycle

| AccountID | CoolOff_Created_DT | CoolOff_End_DT | Endcycle45days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 10-01-2022 00:48 | 13-01-2022 05:00 | 27-02-2022 05:00 |
| 12345 | 13-01-2022 11:43 | 17-01-2022 05:00 | 27-02-2022 05:00 |
| 12345 | 20-01-2022 03:42 | 23-01-2022 05:00 | 27-02-2022 05:00 |
| 12345 | 23-01-2022 15:32 | 29-01-2022 05:00 | 27-02-2022 05:00 |

Next cycle

| AccountID | CoolOff_Created_DT | CoolOff_End_DT | Endcycle45days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 07-03-2022 00:44 | 12-03-2022 05:00 | 26-04-2022 05:00 |
| 12345 | 15-04-2022 04:00 | 21-04-2022 18:00 | 26-04-2022 05:00 |

Comment: Please don't post images

Comment: Hello @SimonMartinelli
Could you please help me in answering above question ?

Comment: Input and Expected output is same right ?

Comment: Hi @Roshan 
Yes input is same - these are the records for one player within his 45 days cycle end 
i should be able to get the next set or cycle  of records for the same player after the cycleend45 days i.e 27-02-2022 05:00 . Next cycle for the player should start after his first cycle end i.e 27-02-2022